# Setting up Delphi XE to use Vim as Default Merge Viewer

Tags: delphi, vim, merge, delphi-xe2

Is it possible to use vim as the default merge viewer for Delphi XE to resolve check-in conflicts?

If so, what parameters do I need to use in the tools->options->Merge Viewer dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, it works.  Put gvim in as the program, the working directory will automatically fill in.

Then use the following parameters:

`-f -d -c "wincmd J" $(OutputFileName) $(MyFileName)  $(BaseFileName) $(TheirFileName)`

[source](http://www.toofishes.net/blog/three-way-merging-git-using-vim/)

[image: Delphi Merge Viewer Settings]

Comment: +1 You know you can accept your own answer as the correct one, right?

Comment: @Ken yeah, but I need to wait 2 days.  Plus I don't know what the parameters actually mean, so there may be a better way!

Comment: The command line parameters (`-f -d -c`) should be in the vim docs, or sometimes if you start apps from the command line with the `/h` or `-h` switch. I use a full version of Beyond Compare instead of the IDE's default, and it's documented in their help file in "command line" and then clicking the link for "Command Line Switches" on that page.